# How to run cron job in Ubuntu instance?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, terraform

How do you run cron job in ubuntu instance?

- - - - - /code/terrform.sh

```
#Identify what in the path variable in the context of your script
* * * * * echo $PATH > ~/cron.log

#Identify the shell being use in your script
* * * * * echo $SHELL > ~/cron.log

#Identify the working directory your cron job natively executes in
* * * * * echo $PATH > ~/cron.log
```

i type crontab -e and pasted this in.

how do i even know if this even ran?

Comment: [S.O._Cron_Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) may help. Good luck.